# How to redirect using AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
function get_login()
{
    hideshow('loading2',1);
    error(0);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "The URL",
        data: $('#logins').serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg){  

            if(parseInt(msg.status)==1)
            {
                succ2(1,msg.txt);                   
                setTimeout('go_to_you_page()', 1000);

            } else if(parseInt(msg.status)==0) {
                error2(1,msg.txt);
            }

            hideshow('loading2',0);
        }
    });

    return false;
}

function go_to_you_page()  
{  
    window.location = 'myaccount.php';     
}
```

If the user is not logged in, it will add `index.php?redirect=inbox.php` (for example)

How can i redirect the user after logging in to the `/inbox.php` ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What exactly is the question? You seem to have the proper code to achieve a redirect based on a link.

Comment: Set the window.location in your success handler or reply with a response redirect in your XHR reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's [some code](http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html) to get a URL parameter:

```
function get_url_parameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
    if ( results == null )
      return "";
    else
      return results[1];
}
```

You can use this in your `go_to_you_page()` function:

```
function go_to_you_page()
{
    var redirect_parameter = get_url_parameter('redirect');

    // redirect to /myaccount.php if the redirect parameter is not set
    var redirect = ( redirect_parameter === "" ) ? 'myaccount.php' : redirect_parameter;

    window.location.href = redirect;
}
```

Comment: Correct answer but according to a post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript) window.location.replace is better to use than window.location.href .Check it out