# AJAX call to Servlet Google App Engine (GAE)

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, google-app-engine, servlets

I am trying to make an AJAX call to my servlet but it doesn't work. I can't redirect to a JSP.

This is my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
            url:   '/register',
            type:  'GET'
    });
```

This is my Servlet:

```
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException {

    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/prueba.jsp").forward(req, resp);

}
```

If I use `resp.sendRedirect("prueba.jsp")`, it does not work, but if I use my browser and put "localhost:8888/register" it works fine!

Please help!

Comment: what you mean by "_it doesn´t work_"? what response do you get? also, it's not clear, are you using `forward()` or `sendRedirect()`?

Comment: There isn´t any response. Both ways are invalid, forward() and sendRedirect(). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot redirect using Ajax. That's the point of Ajax – it's asynchronous, separate from the "main thread".

If you want to simply redirect either:

- Redirect in the Java code after doing some processing
- Have a link in the HTML – `<a href="/register">Register!</a>`
- If you definitely want to use JavaScript to redirect, have a look at [How can I make a redirect page using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-using-jquery)

The last method can be sort-of used with with Ajax. But it's not exactly what you want to do. Have a look at [How to redirect using AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615456/how-to-redirect-using-ajax)

Comment: `forward` is not redirect btw, it produces 200 status with content. so it should work, unless there is something wrong in other part (and "isn't any response" probably confirms that)

Comment: @IgorArtamonov you are probably correct, but from what I gathered, JHJ here just wants to redirect.